# Tabbar Tab Overflow

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

Is there anyway that I can have tabs on an iPhone hide if there is not enough room to display them. The best example I can think of is on Android Music Player the tabs for "Artist", "Albums", "Songs" are displayed but "Recent", "Playlists", "Genres" are hidden to the left or right of these tabs.

[image: Picture of tabs on Android]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no easy way to do that, no. In fact, I doubt the Apple HIG would even allow it.

Should you, however, decide to proceed anyway, you'll want to set the `hidden` property of the UITabBar to `YES`. This will only hide it - you may also have to resize the views.

This entire process definitely isn't trivial nor should it be, since it's something that simply shouldn't be done - users may appreciate the extra space but will immediately get lost.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the tabbar to be hidden, by setting up an IBOutlet. Better yet, code it in such a way that when the user taps the screen, the tabbar appears, similar to a toolbar appearing when user taps the screen. It is very simple to do, and frees up screen space!